# Update p:dataTable after deleting a row with p:confirmDialog

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am using a `p:dataTable` to display a list of players. I have a column to delete the player from the database. This column has a `p:commandButton`, that triggers a `p:confirmDialog`. The confirm dialog button should both exclude the player and refresh the table.
The deletion works just fine, but I can't seem to refresh the data table automatically in any way.

The code is something like this:

The `.xhtml`:

```
<h:form id="form" >
   <p:growl/>
     <div class="bloco">
       <h2>PLAYERS</h2>

         <p:dataTable value="#{adminPlayersBean.players}" var="p"
                      paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="true"
                      paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="8">
// some columns

          <p:column headerText="X">
            <p:commandButton action="#{adminPlayersBean.remove(p)}" 
                             update="@form" immediate="true" 
                             styleClass="ui-button-danger" icon="pi pi-times">
            <p:confirm header="Delete player" message="Delete #{p.getNickname()}?" />
          </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>

// ...


     <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" 
                      responsive="true" width="430" >
                 
        <p:commandButton value="✓ Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes"/>
        <p:commandButton value="X No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" />
     </p:confirmDialog>

//...
```

In the bean:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class AdminPlayersBean implements Serializable {

    private List<Player> players;

    public void remove(Player player) {
        playerController.remove(player);  //deletes the player from DB
        
        this.players = playersController.findAll(); //updates the List that fills the dataTable

        PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update(":form");       
    }
```

I've already tried changing the update from the .xhtml to:

- `update=":form"`
- `update="@form"`
- also, added a "table" id to the `p:dataTable` and tried `update=":form:table"`

In the Bean, I've tried:

- `PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update(":form");`
- `PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("@form");`
- etc

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: If you create a Primefaces Test reproducer that would help us all debug it much better: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Comment: Try moving the update tag in the confirm dialog button